# mysql group by hour - how to avoid wrong results

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

In this table the values of my rain counter are stored. The **correct total is 0.9**
In the RAW Data you can see that at 17:01 the value was set to 1161.5.

By sql query the RAW data are grouped per hour.
In the results only 0.6 rain are shown in the time from 16-17 o'clock.
Unfortunately the 0.3 mm between counter 1161.5 and 1161.2 are missing.

Any idea how I can avoid the error in my sql query?

- **RAW Data** from raincounter:

| id | unixt | date | rainc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15261 | 1666270927 | 2022-10-20 15:02:07 | 1160.6 |
| 15262 | 1666271527 | 2022-10-20 15:12:07 | 1160.6 |
| 15263 | 1666272127 | 2022-10-20 15:22:07 | 1160.6 |
| 15264 | 1666272727 | 2022-10-20 15:32:07 | 1160.6 |
| 15265 | 1666273327 | 2022-10-20 15:42:07 | 1160.6 |
| 15266 | 1666273927 | 2022-10-20 15:52:07 | 1160.6 |
| 15267 | 1666274527 | 2022-10-20 16:02:07 | 1160.6 |
| 15268 | 1666275127 | 2022-10-20 16:12:07 | 1160.6 |
| 15269 | 1666275727 | 2022-10-20 16:22:07 | 1160.6 |
| 15270 | 1666276171 | 2022-10-20 16:29:31 | 1160.9 |
| 15271 | 1666276228 | 2022-10-20 16:30:28 | 1160.9 |
| 15272 | 1666276327 | 2022-10-20 16:32:07 | 1160.9 |
| 15273 | 1666276927 | 2022-10-20 16:42:07 | 1160.9 |
| 15274 | 1666277348 | 2022-10-20 16:49:08 | 1161.2 |
| 15275 | 1666277527 | 2022-10-20 16:52:07 | **1161.2** |
| 15276 | 1666278118 | 2022-10-20 17:01:58 | **1161.5** |
| 15277 | 1666278127 | 2022-10-20 17:02:07 | 1161.5 |
| 15278 | 1666278727 | 2022-10-20 17:12:07 | 1161.5 |
| 15279 | 1666279327 | 2022-10-20 17:22:07 | 1161.5 |
| 15280 | 1666279927 | 2022-10-20 17:32:07 | 1161.5 |

- **MYSQL Query:**

```
SELECT `date`,ROUND(MAX(`rainc`) - MIN(`rainc`),2) AS `rain`, MAX(`rainc`) AS max
FROM`mqtt-weather`.`rainc`
WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() AND `date` < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY HOUR(`date`)
```

- **Result:**

| date | rain | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-20 15:02:07 | 0.00 | 1160.6 |
| **2022-10-20 16:02:07** | 0.60 | **1161.2** |
| **2022-10-20 17:01:58** | **0.00** | **1161.5** |
| 2022-10-20 18:02:07 | 0.00 | 1161.5 |

Comment: Your sample data does not match your result set, please correct.

Comment: i hope my correction looks better

Comment: You need to look at the last row in the previous group (the previous hour) and compare it to the last row in the current group (the current hour), not the min and max values in the same hour. That can be achieved with LAST_VALUE and/or LAG, which are available in MySQL 8. Please specify which version of MySQL you're using. (Also, grouping with the `HOUR` function alone will cause problems your data spans different dates.)

Comment: Version 10.3.36-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 (Raspbian 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH
  lagged AS
(
  SELECT
    r.*,
    LAG(`date`) OVER (ORDER BY unixt) AS prev_date,
    rainc - LAG(rainc) OVER (ORDER BY unixt) AS rainc_delta
  FROM
    `mqtt-weather`.`rainc` AS r
)
SELECT
  MIN(prev_date)     AS interval_start,
  MAX(`date`)        AS interval_end,
  SUM(rainc_delta)   AS interval_rain,
  MAX(rainc)         AS final_rainc
FROM
  lagged
GROUP BY
  unixt DIV 3600
```

***EDIT:*** added demo and corrected typos and integer division.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/fW1ykZxi